# ReferenceError: Pusher is not defined

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-echo

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B443p.png)
Websocket can run well but there is still an error, namely Reference Pusher is not defined, what should I do.

```
export const echoInstance = new Echo({
  broadcaster: "pusher",
  key: process.env.PUSHER_APP_KEY,
  wsHost: process.env.PUSHER_HOST,
  wsPort:  process.env.PUSHER_PORT,
  forceTLS: true,
  disableStats: true,
  encrypted: true,
  cluster:  process.env.PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
  authEndpoint:  process.env.PUSHER_AUTH_ENDPOINT,
  auth: {
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      Authorization:
      `Bearer ${existingToken}`,
    },
  },
  enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
});
```

Comment: Format your code. Use indents; it's more readable and helps solve your issue quicker.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, **error messages**, console output, markup, data, data structures, and other textual information **as text**, not just as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.